# Как использовать переменную для проверки в столбце базы данных

Tags: python, sqlite

Я очень плохо знаю базы данных и не знаю, как вставить python переменную в WHERE запрос в строке:

```
cursor.execute('UPDATE test SET messages = (?) WHERE user_id=(?)', (str(int(messagenum) + 1), usertext, ))
```

С первой переменной все норм, но проверка со вторым восклицательным знаком просто не работает (если напрямую подставить значение вместо знака, но проблем нет).